# Entity Framework Linq to Sql: select from 2 different subqueries based on boolean condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

For example, a timesheet application: the model consists of a `Project` that can be configured to allow work against any `Task`, or only a specified subset of tasks.

When retrieving the data to log a timesheet for this Project, it needs to load the `TaskOptions`. Depending on the `TasksMode` of the Project, this could be all tasks in the database, or only the project's specified `Tasks`.

I have attempted the following EF linq query:

```
var availableTasks = dbContext.Projects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectId == projectId)
    .SelectMany(p => p.TasksMode == ProjectTasksMode.AllowAll
        ? dbContext.Tasks
            .Select(t => new TaskOption {TaskId = t.TaskId, Name = t.Name})
        : p.Tasks.Select(t => t.TaskId)
            .Join(dbContext.Tasks, id => id, t => t.TaskId,
                (tId, t) => new TaskOption {TaskId = tId, Name = t.Name}))
    .ToList();
```

However I get the following `System.NotSupportedException`:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[[MyApp.TaskOption, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[[MyApp.TaskOption, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I'm not sure how I would write this in SQL either, so am struggling to work out how to debug it. I could just use 2 separate db queries, but I think this should be possible.

Comment: At the end of your join, try adding `.AsEnumerable()`. So, it'd be: `(tId, t) => new TaskOption {TaskId = tId, Name = t.Name})).AsEnumerable()`

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but having a property ProjectTasksMode indicating that from a separate table "all data" vs "only where the FK of id matches" is something I'd try to resolve at the schema level. In other words, there's something smelly going on here indicating a totally different problem related to relational data.

Comment: @Rob I think that would turn it into 2 separate db queries. I can definitely do that, but trying to find a way to do it in 1 query.

Comment: @Atoms Can you be more specific with the schema issue? My `Tasks` table contains all possible tasks. The `Project.Tasks` navigation property points to an association table called `ProjectTasks`, that just links each project with a task, ie. a many - many relationship. That association table will only be populated when the project's `TaskMode != AllowAll`

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, if you have a ProjectId property as part of the Task object, I'd think you could try something like:

```
var availableTasks = dbContext.Projects
    .Where(p => p.ProjectId == projectId)
    .SelectMany(p => dbContext.Tasks
        .Where( t => p.TasksMode == ProjectTasksMode.AllowAll || (t.ProjectId == projectId))
        .Select( t => new TaskOption { TaskId = tId, Name = t.Name}))
    .ToList();
```

Although that where condition gets evaluated for every Task in the DB unless the SQL server is doing some magic optimization.

Comment: Interesting! But my `Task` table doesn't link to the `Project` table directly, rather there is a M:M association table `ProjectTasks` with FKs to both. So there is no FK on `Tasks` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this syntax, but the compiler is complaining from different thing!! It can't cast object of type IQueryable To type IEnumerable, so be sure to end the both queries with `.ToList();`

Again, i'm not sure about this syntax beside you have many typos in this example!

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Calling `ToList()` on each subquery will just turn it into multiple db queries, which is what I'm trying to avoid.